# Mute /Silence Android Smart Phone based upon calendar event of "Outlook" app (Microsoft)

Tags: android, automation, calendar, outlook

I am using Microsoft's "Outlook" app for work related emails and calendar events. I have tried many apps for muting the phone on the calendar events but none of them could read Outlook events. Is there any known app that could do the job? Highly appreciate

Comment: Is there any price limit if it comes to paid apps? I could think of *Tasker* being capable of that (see [these search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=tasker+outlook+calendar) for possible recipes), but that app isn't free and most likely requires an addon for outlook which might not be free either.

Answer (score 1):

[IFTTT](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ifttt.ifttt) has an Office 365 calendar connector. If your Outlook app is synced to Office 365, it should do the job.

Btw, I cannot try myself, as I don't have an Office 365 account.